# How to Interact with 2 or More ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, viewmodel

I have written a tool in which a ListBox is bound to a `ObserservableCollection<object>` with varying datatypes I've define. I use a `PropertyDataTemplateSelector` to present the data in the ListBox. The `PropertyDataTemplateSelector` references several `DataTemplates` that are set as `UserControls`. There is a background class that provides logic to the `PropertyDataTemplateSelector` by checking the `object` type and then applying the correct `DataTemplate`.

Here's an abbreviated example of the XAML for the `UserControls` and the `MainWindow`.

UserControl1

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Val1}"
               Style="{StaticResourse Yes}" />

    <Button Content="I'm Button 1"
            Command="{Binding Path=PathtoCommand1}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter1}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled1}" />

    <Button Content="I'm Button 2"
            Command="{Binding Path=PathtoCommand2}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter2}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled2}"
            Tag="{Binding Path="DataContext.TagItem2}">

       <Button.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tag}"
                     DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
         </ContextMenu>
       </Button.ContextMenu>

    </Button>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UserControlN

```
<UserControl x:Class="AwesomerControl">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FancyName2}"
               Style="{StaticResourse Yes}" />

    <Button Content="Clicker 1"
            Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingGreat1}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Greatness1}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsTurnedOn1}" />

    <Button Content="Clicker 2"
            Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingGreat2}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Greaterness2}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsTurnedOn2}"
            Tag="{Binding Path="DataContext.TagItem2}">

       <Button.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
           <MenuItem IsCheckable="True"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tag}"
                     DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
         </ContextMenu>
       </Button.ContextMenu>

    </Button>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here I set the `UserControls` to a specified `DataTemplate`. The UserControls were moved out to make the XAML easier to read/navigate. In actuality the UserControls are a few hundred lines each.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key"Template1">
     <customControls:AwesomeControl/>
  </DataTemplate>
  ...
  <DataTemplate x:Key"TemplateN">
     <customControls:AwesomerControl/>
  </DataTemplate>


  <dts:PropertyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateselector"
                                    Template1="{StaticResource Template1"}
                                    ...
                                    TemplateN="{StaticResource TemplateN"}
</Window.Resources>
```

The `ListBox` is defined as this.

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=CollectionofMyObjects}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateselector}" />
```

I am using a single `ViewModel` to drive the `MainWindow` and the `UserControls`.

So that's where I'm at, essentially. I have this currently working as I'd like, but in an ongoing effort to learn (this is my first MVVM/WPF/C# project) I'd like to keep exploring how to make my code "better" (however that's defined). I'm not looking to solve an error here. So to avoid a general/broad question, I'll ask what I think I want to know. Someone can correct me and I'll update the "question(s)" appropriately

**Question:** How can I go about producing a `ViewModel` for each of the `UserControls`? Some of the `ViewModels`, for the `UserControls`, will occasionally require two-way communication to the `MainWindow_ViewModel`. The main crux of my problem is figuring out how the multiple VMs will communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but it's not *quite* MVVM yet. ;)

1. First, break out all the functionality that is relevant to each `UserControl` into their own classes. These are your view-model classes.
2. Your controls should now become "view" classes, and they deserve their own mark-up file. Rather than use a template selector, you can use the [`DataTemplate.DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to automatically connect the view-model class type to its view.

There are a lot of options for communication between view-models. To further your education, I'd consider looking at a light-weight MVVM framework that has built-in solutions for communication. My personal favorite is [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), which includes an [`EventAggregator`](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation), a service that provides the ability to publish an object from one view-model to another in a loosely-coupled fashion.

Keep learning, you're on the right track!

Comment: Is it really no `MVVM`? From what I'm reading, he's doing it the right way. Can you elaborate it? But you're right, that the modularity could be definitely improved.

Comment: I made a quick edit to make sure we are talking the same thing. Each of my UserControls is defined as a separate view. Is that the modularity that you were discussing? Am I right in assuming that when you say "view" class deserve their own markup files, you mean a separate viewmodel (not the code behind) for those files?

Comment: MVVM should leverage multiple views as well as view-models. If you only have 1 view-model and 1 view (XAML) file, then it should go without saying that you are not taking full advantage of the pattern. :) And Peter, I mean that each of those UserControls should be defined in their own .xaml file (preferably in a "Views" folder).

Comment: Charlie, thanks for the pointers. I think you've given me enough to get me going in the right direction.